# Apache Camel - Definition has no children on Aggregate

Tags: jboss, apache-camel

I am trying to implement an aggregate on Apache Camel (Version: 2.18.0) with the following route:

```
<route id="AggregateExtraRoute">
    <from uri="direct:AggregateExtraRoute"/>
        <aggregate strategyRef="CustomAggregationStrategy">
            <correlationExpression>
                <simple>header.AggregationHeader</simple>
            </correlationExpression>
            <log message="Route After Aggregate: ${body}" loggingLevel="INFO"/>
        </aggregate>
</route>
```

I have also tried:

```
<header>AggregationHeader</header>
```

The error above appears when i am trying to deploy to JBoss.

Comment: In think you need (at least) one  child `<to uri="">` node inside your aggregate. Try to replace your `<log ...>` statement with `<to uri="log:demo"/>` and see if it works better.

Comment: Or add a `<to uri="mock:result"/>` after your <log>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're missing [completion criteria](https://camel.apache.org/components/3.18.x/eips/aggregate-eip.html#_completion). You must provide at least one.

Comment: I added completionSize and it worked, thanks.